# How to use a CVS repository in myeclipse

Tags: java, myeclipse

I am trying to link my java code between two different systems through MyEclipse IDE . I know it is possible via CVS versioning system.

Any help on how to configure and use CVS would be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you have a CVS server setup and you just want to setup client on your machine that connects using Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using CVS, you need CVS server first.
if you want to set it up on windows system download zip and install from

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/cvsgui/files/WinCvs/
```

If your system is linux based install procedure is mentioned clearly in

```
http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/cvs/pserver.htm
```

The repository is where the different versions are stored. You need to then import your project into the repository. Then you need to use commands

- **cvs checkout**    (To make a local copy of a module's files from the repository)
- **cvs update**        (To update your copy of a module with any changes from the central repository)
- **cvs commit**        (When you think your files are ready to be merged back into the repository for the rest of your developers to
  see)

A very good reference of commands is found in below link

```
http://wwwasd.web.cern.ch/wwwasd/cvs/tutorial/cvs_tutorial_3.html
```

Hope this helps.